# Using a webservice API in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Currently I am trying to utilize this API documented here:
http://www.sentimentanalysisonline.com/page/documentation/

I am trying to use the getScore() web function but it keeps giving me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: s
>      at System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s)
>      at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
>      at NaturalLanguageProcessing.SentimentScore.GetScore(String searchXML) in D:\Jinu\FromJinu\BrandWatchPro\Feeds Fetching Projects\NaturalLanguageProcessing\NaturalLanguageProcessing\SentimentScore.asmx.cs:line 204

This is what I have in my code so far:

```
$input = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
 <apikey>$apikey</apikey>
 <QueryItems>
      <query>
                <id>unique identifier 1</id>
                <brandname><![CDATA[This is the end]]></brandname>
                <paragraph><![CDATA[This is really bad, the world is about to end. HELP]]></paragraph>
      </query>
</QueryItems>
</root>
EOD;

$client = new SoapClient('http://api.sentimentanalysisonline.com/sentimentscore.asmx?WSDL');
$client->getScore($input);
```

The API key is free to obtain for you to try it out yourself too. Is this how you correctly call a webfunction, through SOAP? I am new to using API's so I am trying to learn and read as much as I can.

Comment: `parameter name: s`. since you don't seem to have an `s` in your sample text, either you're not providing a required parameter, or something you're inserting into there (apikey?) is causing an XML malformation. Plus, `"$var"` in PHP is redundant. `getScore($input)` is all that's necessary. there is no point in creating a new string, stuffing a string into that new string, and then firing off the new string. just pass the original string as is.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so quickly!
$apikey is as it is because I don't want to release my apikey, if you need it to test I can give you mine. What I don't understand is the `parameter name: s`. The function GetScore(string input) only requires a xml with the specifics that I have already coded above (according to the documentation provided by the API). The getscore function doesn't require any other parameters, to my understanding at least. I am new to this so sorry if I sound really ignorant :P

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to query the server using SOAP ? That looks like an rpc-like api to me, but I can't find any thing about soap, rest ou anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load Wsdl file into SoapUI. It will create mock request envelope for you and will let you send the requests to webservice. According to wsdl, you should be sending xml as requestXML property.

Try this:

$client->getScore((object)array('requestXML' => $input));